# What security benefit is there in 2020 to block outbound Ping

Tags: firewalls, icmp, ping

I've researched this and found the following on StackExchange and ServerFault, but they're very old.

https://serverfault.com/questions/55889/why-block-outbound-icmp

[Is it a bad idea for a firewall to block ICMP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711/is-it-a-bad-idea-for-a-firewall-to-block-icmp)

[Security risk of PING?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/security-risk-of-ping)

So, as of now (mid-2020) is there any valid security reason to block outbound ping on one's server.

Comment: Instead of duplicating existing questions, we should bring attention to those questions to make sure they are still accurate,

Comment: Most infosec questions can be answered with "It depends" and this is definitely one of them. Some environments will block icmp while others will allow it or at least allow certain types. What service(s) need to send icmp? Why? To what destination? What icmp types? So on and so forth.

Comment: @schroeder Closing this by directing me to an answer which was one of the posts I mentioned that didn't answer it isn't appropriate.
I said that the answers I found are very old - in the case of the suggestion you made that's over 7-years old.  In security and internet terms, those are in dog year.
So my question stands and should be re-opened:  _Today_ in mid 2020 are there any actual security reasons for blocking outbound ping, or for that matter ICMP altogether?  Surely techniques that exploit pinging have long been mitigate?

Comment: I have explained. It is not appropriate to repost the same question. It is appropriate to update the old question.